# Dynamic JPA query not working

Tags: java, jpa

I am using join query through createQuery in JPA. I have 2 tables **MasterScrip** and **OrderMaster**. Entity code is given below. The dynamic query is returning collection object. I debugged and found that the query executes and returns collection object correctly; but, after the object returned an error, shown below:

```
   [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
    javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException...

    SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/ClientTemplate/orderReport.xhtml]
    javax.el.ELException: /ClientTemplate/orderReport.xhtml @14,142 value="#{stockOrderBean.scripLst}": com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://service/}getOrderScripByUserNameResponse but found: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
```

Stateless bean method:

```
 public Collection<MasterScrip> getOrderScripByUserName(String userName)
{        
    try
    {
        String squery = "select DISTINCT(s.scripSymbol),s.scripID from MasterScrip s,OrderStock o where o.scripID.scripID = s.scripID and o.userName.userName = '" + userName + "'";
        Collection<MasterScrip> c = em.createQuery(squery).getResultList();
        //UserMaster um = em.find(UserMaster.class,userName);
        return c;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

What is the cause of this error? How do I solve it?

Comment: It is bad-bad idea to construct queries from parameters. Use parameters instead. Read about this problem called 'SQL injection'

Comment: but the query is working fine i guess as it is returning the desired result

Comment: are you suggesting me to use setParameter?

Comment: yes setParameter is safe thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as noted in the comments, you should always use parameters instead of concatenating parameter values:

```
select DISTINCT(s.scripSymbol), s.scripID from MasterScrip s, OrderStock o 
where o.scripID.scripID = s.scripID and o.userName.userName = :userName
```

This would prevent SQL injection attacks, or simply incorrect queries in case of a user name like `O'Reilly` for example.

Your query returns two different columns. There is no way for such a query to magically return instances of `MasterScrip`. It returns a `List<Object[]>`, where each `Object[]` contains two values: the `scripSymbol` and the `scripID`.

The query would return instances of MasterScrip if it was

```
select distinct s from MasterScrip s, OrderStock o 
where o.scripID.scripID = s.scripID and o.userName.userName = :userName
```